# IF and assignment statement are Thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

```
private LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
private synchronized int foo(int x){
    if(x>=0){ //do something
        list.add(x);
        return x    }
    else {

        int tmp = list.removeFirst();
        return tmp;
    }

    return -1;
}
public void test(int id)
{
    if(foo(id)==-1)
        //do something
        }

public void test2(int id){
    int y=foo(id);
    System.out.println(id+" "+ y);
}
```

if the test and test2 method has been accessed by multiple threads is thread-safe meanwhile test and test2 are not declared synchronized?
Ps sorry i correct the code

Comment: This code isn't legal. But it is thread safe. No shared variables are being modified. All I see is local variables.

Comment: `// do something` needs elaboration, but the two comments above are correct.  `id` and `x` are local variables, are primitives and therefore copies.  There's nothing that can go wrong even if you remove the `synchronized`.

Comment: @markspace you need to synchronize the access to list because class LinkedList is not thread safe.

Comment: Ah, didn't see that, or it was added later.  You're right, the linked list needs to be protected. @Donat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is threadsafe if you don't touch the list anywhere but in the code you provided. If you doubt yet - provide all the code.

### Short explanation:

Method `foo` uses a `List` object that can be shared between threads, but the list created during object instantiation so there is HB between write and read it. The method itself is synchronized so there is HB relationship between every reads and writes into the list.

In your `test` and `test2` methods you don't use any objects that can be shared between different threads, and you use only foo method that is threadsafe so the methods are threadsag.

**PS:** But if you modify the list field, or work with the list inside other methods it depends on how exectly you do it.

Comment: Is not possibile that a thread  A undergoes preemption after go out of foo metod so a second thread B enter in foo   Go out too and undergoes preemption before the assignment and result of thread A swap on thread B? Sorry  again for my English

Comment: @screatives, I am not sure that I understood you right, but Java memory model guaranties that all changes made by thread A inside method `foo` will be visible by thread B when B enters into method `foo`. And only one thread can be inside method `foo` at moment.

Comment: Yep I know it but I talk about the method test and test2 the  statement assignment is atomic? I mean could be happened the thread A after finish the method foo and before the assignment undergoes preemption and another thread enter in the foo finish too and preemption again so now the system.out print y of thread A and Id of thread B?

Comment: @screatives no, each thread will get it's own y, and that y will be used to construct `id+" "+ y`